# jQuery Datepicker working in Safari, but not FF or Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I've simplified the code to hopefully make it easier to figure out.

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="script.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"
      href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>

<div type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

I've uploaded both my HTML and javascript files on my school's hosting space [here](https://www.msu.edu/~ftounisa/test/). When I visit the link on Safari the calendar shows up fine but when I open it on Firefox or Chrome nothing happens.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schools hosting uses SSL, so it's an `https://` link.

When a user visits a page served over HTTP, their connection is open for eavesdropping and man-in-the-middle attacks.
When a user visits a page served over HTTPS, their connection with the web server is authenticated and encrypted with SSL and hence safeguarded from eavesdroppers and man-in-the-middle attacks.

However, if an HTTPS page includes HTTP content, the HTTP portion can be read or modified by attackers, even though the main page is served over HTTPS.

When an HTTPS page has HTTP content, we call that content “mixed”. The webpage that the user is visiting is only partially encrypted, since some of the content is retrieved unencrypted over HTTP.

Chrome and Firefox now has [Mixed Content Blockers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content) that blocks certain HTTP requests on HTTPS pages.

For security reasons Firefox and Chrome will block any scripts not loaded from a `https` adress when the page loading those scripts is using `https`.

To fix it, simply change the URL's of your scripts from

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js
```

to

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js
```

Google supports both.
And use a current version of jQuery, version 1.4 is half a decade old !

Comment: I knew it was something simple like this but couldn't figure it out for the life of me. You're a life saver!